# RadioField never validates correctly

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm new to flask and try to build a simple demographics survey. While validating a `StringField` (e.g. Nationality) works fine, I have trouble with the `RadioField`. No error messages occur if I don't provide any input for the `RadioField`. I think the problem lies in my jinja2 template but I'm not able to find what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

extract from main.py:

```
class DemographicsForm(FlaskForm):
Gender = RadioField(
                    'Gender',
                    choices=[('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other')],
                    validators=[InputRequired()]
                    )


@app.route("/demographics", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def demographics():
    form = DemographicsForm()
    return render_template('demographics.html', title='Demographic Information', form=form)
```

extract from demographics.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.Gender.label(class='radio') }}

    {% if form.Gender.errors %}
       {{ form.Gender(class='radio is-invalid') }}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {% for error in form.Gender.errors %}
                <span>{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ form.Gender(class='radio') }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: if I understood correctly, you would like to generate an error message when no radio button is selected. That's right?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem comes from your Jinja code. The way you implemented error handling is pretty confusing. It should be as simple as this one:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.Gender.label(class='radio') }}
    {{ form.Gender(class='radio') }}
    {% for error in form.Gender.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Thus, when you send the form without having selected a radio button, an error message will appear on your page (in the code above it will appear in red) and in your console.

[More details here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/wtforms/)

Comment: That's a different way, but it works, thanks! I was following a tutorial from Corey Schafer on Youtube and he did all his validation process this way, that's why I wanted to implement it for all `Field` types. I'm still unsure why it only works for some fields...maybe this has something to do with it (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26402). If I find the problem I will post it here.